# pandas how to avoid iterations on rows? applying function with params on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

using python 3.7+

want to split paragraphs into new rows using `scispicy`. need to use Spicy on each row to get the relevant result (not just `split('.')`). Is it possible with pandas vectorization? any help would be much appreciated

have this df -

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
...                    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
...                    'some_description': ['falcons have wings. falcons fly', 'dog have 4 legs. they are the best', 'spiders create webs. spiders have 8 legs', 'fish swims. fish lives in water']},
...                    index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
>>> df
        num_legs  num_wings  some_description
falcon         2          2   'falcons have wings. falcons fly'
dog            4          0   'dog have 4 legs. they are the best'
spider         8          0   'spiders create webs. spiders have 8 legs'
fish           0          0   'fish swims. fish lives in water'
```

have this function I want to apply on each row -

```
def split_to_sentences(text, nlp):
  doc = nlp(text)
  return list(doc.sents)
```

where nlp is `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_sm")`
I want to iterate over rows and split every sentence into 2 so the result would be -

```
        num_legs  num_wings  some_description
falcon         2          2   'falcons have wings.'
falcon         2          2   'falcons fly.'
dog            4          0   'dog have 4 legs'
dog            4          0   'they are the best'
spider         8          0   'spiders create webs'
spider         8          0   'spiders have 8 legs'
fish           0          0   'fish swims.'
fish           0          0   'fish lives in water'
```

maybe the only way is with iterrows/itertuples (which I understand are [bad practice](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-iterating-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-7dd5f9992c01))?

## edit 2 -

I understand apply is also a bad practice, is it possible to use something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'some_description'
df.assign(some_description=df[a].str.split(r'\. ')).explode(a)
```

result:

```
        num_legs    num_wings   some_description
falcon  2           2           falcons have wings
falcon  2           2           falcons fly
dog     4           0           dog have 4 legs
dog     4           0           they are the best
spider  8           0           spiders create webs
spider  8           0           spiders have 8 legs
fish    0           0           fish swims
fish    0           0           fish lives in water
```

Comment: thank you! just edited my question since I want to use Spicy to split the sentences, str.split('.') or with regex won't be useful in my case (larger data set). is it still possible?